# Running PowerBI playground solution, changes not appearing in web site

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, powerbi

I am trying to create a custom Power BI visual using the MS Power BI Playground project (downloaded from git).  I installed VS 2015 community edition and have loaded up the solution, it builds with no errors, and I can run and browse it fine. The solution is written in type script,  uses a startup project ("PowerBIVusuals") which loads sample BI visuals from another project ("Visuals") in the same solution.  If I make changes to the Visuals project .ts files, these changes are not visible when I run the "PowerBIVisuals" project.  I am making sure all projects are rebuilt, cleared the browser cache etc, no success.  This type of project seems to use no binaries, so not sure where it compiles.  Any assistance appreciated in trying to understand the workings of this project.